# cannot get test script to work, containers don't seem to talk to each other

Tags: docker, docker-compose

So I have a big `docker-compose.yaml` of which I have stripped the parts that do not seem relevant:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  server-test:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/server/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "38478:38478"
    depends_on:
      - postgres-test
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=test-docker
      - LOG=show
    command: yarn server secret

  tester:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/tester/Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - server-test
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=test-docker
      - LOG=show

  postgres-test:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: test
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: test
      POSTGRES_DB: test-yt_rec_graph
    ports:
      - "5433:5432"
    expose:
      - 5432
    volumes:
      - test-yt_rec_graph:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

The idea is if I run `docker compose run tester` my tests should run...

But I get tons of
`FetchError: request to http://server-test:38478/testing/clearDb failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.29.0.3:38478` errors.

So **it seems** the `tester` cannot speak with the `server`... even though the node server  is listening on all interfaces and doesn't spit in my face so it seems to connect to the db just fine...

The Dockerfile for `tester` is:

```
FROM node:18

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y wget gnupg \
  && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \
  && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
  && apt update \
  && apt install -y google-chrome-stable \
                    fonts-ipafont-gothic \
                    fonts-wqy-zenhei \
                    fonts-thai-tlwg \
                    fonts-kacst \
                    fonts-freefont-ttf libxss1 \
                    bash --no-install-recommends
COPY . /root/yt_rec_graph
WORKDIR /root/yt_rec_graph
RUN yarn
RUN npm install pm2 -g
RUN pm2 install typescript
CMD yarn jest
```

And that for `server-test`:

```
FROM node:18

COPY . /root/yt_rec_graph
WORKDIR /root/yt_rec_graph
RUN yarn
RUN pm2 install typescript

EXPOSE 38472/tcp
EXPOSE 38478/tcp
```

I have tried many things to no avail.

Any cues as what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: How is the timing? Maybe the tester is trying to make connections before the server is ready. Can you set `sleep 10s && yarn jest` as command: for tester to make sure the server is up? What does the log of server-tester say?
Instead of starting only tester with `docker compose run`, try `docker compose up -d` and look at the container logs. To check Connection issues - open shells in the running containers `docker exec -it <container> bash`and try to ping the other containers.

Comment: Ok so the logs don't display anything interesting when running docker-compose up -d. I tried adding the sleep, no change. If I bash into tester it can ping server-test fine, and server-test pings postgres-test fine...

Comment: on fiurther investigation, even though all containers ping one another, it seems the server cannot connect to the database

Comment: And the tester cannot get a simple route not involving the db from the server...